# I want to get last row in mysql using group by

Tags: mysql, sql, groupwise-maximum

```
SELECT * FROM msg_messages m 
JOIN msg_status s on m.messageId = s.messageId 
JOIN msg_threads t ON t.threadId = m.threadId 
JOIN users u ON u.userId = s.userId 
WHERE t.threadId = 1 
GROUP BY u.userId ORDER BY `m`.`date` DESC
```

this is the query which give me always first index of every record. but i want get latest index in each group.. i tried many ways but result is nothing. 
user:
[image: this is without grope by]

[image: this is with grope by]

[image: this is what i want after group by]

[image: this is what giving to me]

Comment: this should be return what you expected ?

Comment: it give nice result but I want last row of every group it give me 1st row of every group by

Comment: It's tragic, and speaks volumes about the limitations of this otherwise brilliant forum, that the single-most frequently asked question under the MyQSL tag is so often answered incorrectly (or incoherently), as below :-(

Comment: First of all, it's obviously non-sensical to return all columns in this query. Which ones do you actually want?

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved? Where's the index column you are talking about?

Comment: @Strawberry i want the all above mentioned column.

Comment: If you want to view all column, then I think group by is not needed. Only use group by if you want to select certain column with some record summarized with aggregate function. I'd like to confirm you the issue, if you don't mind. With "latest index in each group", is it "userId" column you mean with group? and which column you mean with "index"? or it is column index that you mean?

Comment: @andre_northwind i want just last record of every group not all rows :)

Comment: I revised my answer, but nevermind. It didn't worked. sorry.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1. NOTE THAT threads AND users tables are probably redundant for this exercise and can be omitted for simplicty

Comment: See the tag I added.

Answer (score -1):

TRY THIS CODE

```
SELECT * FROM msg_messages m 
JOIN msg_status s on m.messageId = s.messageId 
JOIN msg_threads t ON t.threadId = m.threadId 
JOIN users u ON u.userId = s.userId 
WHERE t.threadId = 1 
GROUP BY u.userId ORDER BY `m`.`date` DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

Answer (score -1):

how about this:

```
SELECT * FROM msg_messages m 
JOIN msg_status s on m.messageId = s.messageId 
JOIN msg_threads t ON t.threadId = m.threadId 
JOIN users u ON u.userId = s.userId 
GROUP BY u.userId 
having max (`m`.`date`)
ORDER BY `m`.`date` DESC
```

I revised my query from

```
having max (`t`.`threadId`)
```

to

```
having max (`m`.`date`)
```

Comment: sorry gab, I tried several times, but still can't get what you want. Lets wait for someone with better SQL skill and logic.

Answer (score -1):

you can use LIMIT 1 after DESC then you will get last record.
example:
DESC 
LIMIT 1;

Comment: it giving me only one record brother